# sshpass with -f is working but not with -p

Tags: ssh, scp, sshpass

I tried to transfer a file from one server to another, for that I used sshpass utility and passed the password with -p option.
sshpass -p ***** scp test.txt username@x.x.x.x:/path

Initially it was working fine, now its not taking the password with -p option. When i passed password via file its taking.
sshpass -f file.txt scp test.txt username@x.x.x.x:/path, this i have tried and its working fine.

Expectation: I need to pass password with -p only.

Could anyone please let me know what might be the issue?

Comment: Hello, can you show the error message produced by `sshpass`, or elaborate about how it's not working anymore? Also, has the password changed, does it contain unusual characters? Do you supply it between single quotes, to prevent any shell expansion?